# JSTL value in href

Tags: jsp, jstl, href

i want to pass a value which is inside JSTL to href,

`<td><a href="coursematerial.jsp?param1=value1"><c:out value="${row.COURSEID}"/></a></td>`

how could i pass the value which is shown through  tag through the href ?

Answer (score 0):

suppose your value in jstl is just like :`<c:out value="${myid}"/>`then you can use just like belows:

```
<c:url value="coursematerial.jsp" var="myURL">
    <c:param name="param1" value="${myid}" />
</c:url>
```

and `<a href="${myURL}"><c:out value="${row.COURSEID}"/></a>`.

Answer (score -1):

in the jsp where we get the parameter do this
`<td><a href="coursematerial.jsp?param1=${row.COURSEID}">` 
use a hidden input type and get parameter value in the cousematerial.jsp,

`<input type="hidden" name="courseid" value=<%= request.getParameter("param1") %> >`